# Get TFS TestPlans for a particular Iteration via the API

Tags: tfs, microsoft-test-manager

I assume this is a rather easy question to answer, but how would I go ahead and query my ITestManagementTeamProject instance for all .TestPlans that have a particular Iteration (and/or Area path) assigned? the ITestManagementTeamProject has a .TestPlans.Query(..) method, but I was wondering what the actual, correct query syntax would be for querying against a particular iteration/area path value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:
`.TestPlans.Query("Select * From TestPlan Where Iteration = 'TeamProject Name\Iteration Name'")`
The Iteration Name appears as it does in the WorkItem "Classification" > "Iteration" as
 *"Team Project Name\Iteration Name"*